# Python:getting error in for loop

Tags: python

i am trying to control an instrument using python. During the code i need to reissue the same command again and again to read the data from the instrument. when i use command for 1 time i get the answer but i have it in for loop i get the data with message "ERR". i am not sure how to resolve this, can anyone help me? below is my code and its output:

```
import visa

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources())
my_instrument = rm.open_resource('TCPIP0::169.254.164.61::3602::SOCKET', read_termination='\r\n')
for i in range(0, 10):
    my_instrument.ask('RMMEAS\r')
    ry3 = my_instrument.read()
    print(ry3)
```

Output

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/nishant.mittal/PycharmProjects/demo.py/kjbkn.py
('TCPIP0::192.168.001.020::3602::INSTR', 'ASRL3::INSTR', 'ASRL4::INSTR', 'ASRL10::INSTR')
8,0.022,0.027,0.029,0.042,0.056,

ERR 
8,0.022,0.027,0.029,0.042,0.056,

ERR 
8,0.022,0.027,0.029,0.042,0.056,

ERR 
8,0.022,0.027,0.029,0.042,0.056,

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you word it abit more clear please, struggling to understand what you mean.

Comment: when i issue the RMEAS command without loop, there is no error. But when i put this command in for loop, i get ERR message along with my data.

Comment: Which version of pyvisa are you using.    Reading the docs for it there is a comment that you should use my_instrument.query("*IDN?"))   instead of my_instrument.ask if you are migrating from a version less than 1.5....  http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=.ask

Comment: you may be polling too quickly. Check the status of the instrument by calling  last_status and checking the [statusCode](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/constants.html#pyvisa.constants.StatusCode) returned

Comment: Also, it looks like the old ask method does a write followed by a read, so you might not need to do a .read to get the result (see [Ask vs. query](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#ask-vs-query))

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried something like this, but I'm guessing that since it prints out

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I assume it works, since exit code 0 means that it compiled correctly (according to C and C++), just not the way you want it to. I also think this is correct because it doesn't print out a `traceback` error.

This is a error in Python:

```
>>> while True print('Hello world')
File "<stdin>", line 1
    while True print('Hello world')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I honestly don't know how to help you more than this... Sorry... :(

I hope I help with this!

Comment: Hello all,
i am able to solve the problem by making a very simple change:
my_instrument.ask('RMMEAS\r') to my_instrument.ask('RMMEAS''). 

Now the next problem is how send multiple commands to the instrument together and receive the data.